# What is wrong with this time conversion code?

Tags: c

I wrote this code to convert set of Universal Times into Local times.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define T_SIZE 2

void Time_change(int time,
             int time_diff,
             int *new_timep,
             int *day_nump)
{
*day_nump=0;

*new_timep=time+(time_diff*100);
if(*new_timep<0)
{
  *new_timep +=2400;
  *day_nump -=1;
}
if(*new_timep>2400)
{
  *new_timep -=2400;
  *day_nump +=1;
}
}

int main(void)
{
int utc[T_SIZE],
    time_diff,
    local[T_SIZE],
    day[T_SIZE],
    i;

    for(i=0;i<T_SIZE;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter Universal Time #%d\n",i);
        scanf("%d",&utc[i]);
        printf("Time difference=");
        scanf("%d",&time_diff);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<T_SIZE;++i)
    {
        Time_change(utc[i],time_diff,&local[i],&day[i]);
        printf("Local Time = %d:%d  day# %d\n",(local[i]/100)%100,(local[i])%100,day[i]);
    }
   system("pause");
    }
```

this result came up

[Image](http://www.mediafire.com/view/myfiles/#ps7sryupt12skuu)

but when I commented these lines

```
//*day_nump -=1;

//*day_nump +=1;
```

the result was right in the Hours Section.

[Image](http://www.mediafire.com/view/myfiles/#ah6vmkc18ay1nls)

What is wrong?

Comment: Were the PNG files your actual output? If not, for plain text output, please just copy it into your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second time you input `time_diff`, it will overwrite the first one, and then the second one will be used twice.

If you move the call to `Time_change` to the first loop, it will use the correct value of `time_diff` each time.